# Is access token in GoogleApiClient saved (Android Drive SDK)?

Tags: android, api, google-drive-api

I'm working on integrating Google Drive Android SDK into my app like it's done in the [demo app](https://github.com/googledrive/android-delete/blob/master/app/src/main/java/drive/play/android/samples/com/drivedeletesample/) and i'm able to auth, list the entries, etc. I'm wondering if i should [connect()](https://github.com/googledrive/android-delete/blob/master/app/src/main/java/drive/play/android/samples/com/drivedeletesample/MainActivity.java#L202) `GoogleApiClient` instance each time the app is started or is it done automatically?

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .addApi(Drive.API)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
    .build();

 mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

Shouldn't i get oauth2 access token after it's [connected](https://github.com/googledrive/android-delete/blob/master/app/src/main/java/drive/play/android/samples/com/drivedeletesample/MainActivity.java#L349) and store it between app launch sessions.

Answer (score 0):

The example you linked to uses Google Drive Android API, which is an offline API that manipulates Drive files on your device. Therefore there is no OAuth and no Access Token. Google Play Services take care of syncing your device files with Google Drive automagically.

As an aside, it would never make sense to store an Access Token as they typically expire after one hour.

Comment: According to the readme "Google Drive Android API Delete Sample app demonstrates deleting of DriveResources via the Google Drive Android API available in Google Play Services. " GDAA is definitely not a wrapper for the REST service. It's a native Android API manipulating local copies of files.